# Request Useragent in Mojolicious

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I am trying to read the UserAgent from a request and perform operations based on it.
Can anyone tell me, how I can get request UserAgent in Mojolicious.

Thanks.

Comment: I figured it out

$req->headers->user_agent.

Comment: Post your answer and mark it as accepted. Better yet, show the code in the context of a simple but complete working example.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I figured it out: `$req->headers->user_agent`